# Add product cart with Fetch API Shopify

Tags: javascript, shopify

I am trying to add a product to the cart with shopify fetch api.
I have created this code, but I can not add the product to the cart.
any help please?

```
let submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');
let variantId = submitButton.getAttribute('data-variant-id');

let newVariantIdArray = variantId.split(',');

let product_data = newVariantIdArray.map(variantId => {
    return {quantity: 1, id: variantId}
  })

let data = {
    items: product_data
  }
   

function addToCart(data) {
  const cartData = data

  fetch('/cart/add.js', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify(cartData),
  })
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error(error))
}

submitButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()

  addToCart(variantId)
})

console.log(data)
```

Comment: What is the error? Do you get any log?

Comment: cartData is not defined and post 400 error.  refreshes the page but does not show the product in the cart

Comment: POST https://foodcl.myshopify.com/cart/add.js 400

Comment: The variant ID is being passed as "data". The request body probably looks something like `{ 12345457 }`. Your locally scoped "data" is overwriting your globally scoped "data" variable.